# Saving object state on Java without using external memory

Tags: java, serialization

Good day.
I know that in order to save object state in Java I should use serialization. But in every single topic about serialization states that I must save my object somewhere (disk, network). My problem is that I'm not allowed to do so. I need a way to save and recover object state without writing it on "external" memory. Maybe to save it on heap or stack... 
Please don't offer to clone it, I'm not allowed to do so as well.
Thanks.

Comment: The question is fundamentally flawed, you cannot save the object if you are not allowed to use any persistent storage. Heap/stack are in-memory, they exist only as long as the program is running.

Comment: What I actually need is only save current state, invoke some function, check "Postconditions", and If some of them doesn't met - restore the object's state to saved one. All of the above without external memory. I can't see any flaws here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can serialize to a [`ByteArrayOuputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).  Just pass one to the [ObjectOutputStream constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#ObjectOutputStream%28java.io.OutputStream%29).  When you're done, you can call [`toByteArray`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray())

Comment: That's can be a solution. Thanks!